# Какой знак используется в R statistics для перечисления?

Tags: строки, dataframe, r, статистика, таблицы

Какой знак используется в R statistics для перечисления? Например, если нужно выбрать несколько номеров строк/колонок?

Как выделить из большой таблицы (Table1) некую нужную часть (Table2)?

```
Table2 <- Table1 [1,]
```

Выделяет первую строку из большой таблицы. А мне, допустим нужны строки 1, 3 и 37. Как записать три цифры вместо одной?

```
#As frame

Table2 <- subset(Table2, cont=="l")
```

Выделяет только строки, у которых в столбце "cont" значение "l". А мне надо "l" и "h".

```
Table2 <- subset(Table2, cont=="l" <какой здесь знак?> "h")
```

Comment: вектор надо использовать: `таблица[c(1,3,37),]`

Comment: спасибо, спасибо